# Video translator

Tags: video

I'm in a situation where I need to listen to an interview recording, but I don't understand the language. So, I need to translate the audio of the video into English. I was looking for some free tools that can do that, but couldn't find. Perhaps you have some tips. Thanks :)

Comment: Not a UX question. But (1) use a transcription tool. e.g. Otter AI. You get some basic amount of transcription for free. (2) Take the resulting text and paste it into Google Translate. (3) optionally take the output and put it into a text to speech system if you really want to listen instead of read.